# Replace a command in bash with other based on parameters

Tags: linux, shell, bash

There is a command, which takes multiple arguments, but depending upon the argument, I have to alter the original command itself, how can it be done at the shell through .bashrc?

Example:

- `command -a -1` should act as `command -a -1`
- `command -a -2` should act as `command -a -2`
- `command -a -4` should act as `command -a -4`
- but `command -a -3` should run `myscript.sh`.

Sorry for the ill formatted question, new to the forum.

Comment: create a function `command` and apply this logic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a function:

```
somename() {
    if [[ $1 = "-a" && $2 = "-3" ]]
    then myscript.sh
    else command somename "$@"
    fi
}
```

I've used `somename` as the name of the command you're replacing, to avoid confusion with the `command` builtin that's used to execute it without going through the function again.